# Creating an if statement for two tkinter shapes entering the same coordinates?

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, coordinates, tkinter-canvas

I've been doing some research online and toying around with my code, but I can't seem to figure out how to create an `if` statement for my shapes created using `tkinter-canvas`.

It's difficult to word this correctly, but I would like to know how to create a condition where if two of my shapes enter the same coordinate area, I can make something happen.

How would you identify your shape or `tags = " "` in the statement? Would you create a boolean statement for if it is in a certain coordinate range?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ()
y = ()

c.coords(x)
v.coords(y)

if x == y:
    print("gaming")
```

So, x and y are list vars when you do canvas.coords it gives you (x1, y1, x2, y2) etc so if you compare then both and they are the same this is a way you can do something.

Comment: So would the `v` and `c` before `.coords` be the tag of the object I'm identifying or are they just placeholders? Or would I enter the desired coordinates of each object in the list variables?